# Почему не сохраняется кодировка в PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, utf-8, кодировка

При попытке сделать запись в бд получил вот такую ошибку:

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9f in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"
```

Следуя оф. документации делал следующее

```
postgres=# show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 LATIN1
(1 row)
```

Ввожу команду на смену кодировки

```
postgres=# SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET
postgres=# show client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Далее выхожу из этого всего и иду делать миграции - такая же ошибка. Захожу в бд, проверяю кодировку - LATIN1

Как мне сохранить значение UTF8 навсегда?

Comment: Данная команда действует на время сессии. Если надо насовсем, то согласно [ответам на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090858/how-do-you-change-the-character-encoding-of-a-postgres-database): сделать дамп, удалить БД, создать новую БД используя другую кодировку, восстановить данные из дампа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы задать client_encoding по умолчанию можно сделать:

```
ALTER DATABASE "<name>" SET client_encoding TO 'UTF-8';
```

Но правильно было бы всегда задавать кодировку на стороне клиента. В частности `psql` это делает сама в соответствии с настройками терминала.